# SaveFileDialog extension added unexpectedly on multidotExtension

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, savefiledialog

I have a problem with the save file dialog. The save file dialog looks fine until I change the `save as type` in the file dialog. It always add the extension that already exists. I need to have the multidot extenstion.

So, if I change the `save as type`, the save file dialog will make the filename become `D:\Temp\Test.dt.dt.dt.dt.dt.dt.txt`
How to make the file the `.dt` not added when I switch the `save as type`

Is this a windows bug ? I am using winform and .net3.5
Here is how I reproduce it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog
                             {
                               Title = "Save list file",
                               Filter =  "Text Files (*.dt.txt)|*.dt.txt|Microsoft Excel Files (*.dt.xls)|*.dt.xls|Microsoft Excel XML Files (*.dt.xlsx)|*.dt.xlsx",
                               DefaultExt = ".dt.txt",
                               OverwritePrompt = true,
                               SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true,
                               AddExtension = true
                             };
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "D:\\Temp\\test.dt.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your code. It works fine for me. What happens if you just use .txt instead of .dt.txt? If nothing else you can try the old standby of either exiting visual studio and coming back in, or reboot your system and re-trying it again to see if that works.

Comment: I can reproduce it in vs2013, winforms, .net 4.5.1, windows 8.1

Comment: @SteveFerg, Have you tried changing "save as type" when the save file dialog open ?I need to keep multi extension because the software already run for some years, and removing this might remove the backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in [FileDialog.cs:line877](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FileDialog.cs,877).
It calls `string currentExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);` to get current extension of selected file and here is the code for `Path.GetExtension(fileName);`

```
// Returns the extension of the given path. The returned value includes the
// period (".") character of the extension except when you have a terminal period when you get String.Empty, such as ".exe" or
// ".cpp". The returned value is null if the given path is
// null or if the given path does not include an extension.
//
[Pure]
public static String GetExtension(String path) {
    if (path==null)
        return null;

    CheckInvalidPathChars(path);
    int length = path.Length;
    for (int i = length; --i >= 0;) {
        char ch = path[i];
        if (ch == '.')
        {
            if (i != length - 1)
                return path.Substring(i, length - i);
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }
        if (ch == DirectorySeparatorChar || ch == AltDirectorySeparatorChar || ch == VolumeSeparatorChar)
            break;
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

that does not support multi dotted extension. so I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't add double extension**

The file extension is supposed to be after the last `.` in the file's name.

**Explanation:**

Your extension is `.dt.txt`:

In this case, the extension will be `.txt`. It will consider `.dt` as the part of the file name(this is the reason of repetitive `.dt`) and `.txt` as the extension.

Comment: based on [SupportMultiDottedExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.supportmultidottedextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), we can add it to support multidotextension. I can understand if it is considered as the part of the filename if I add the extension myself, however, if the file dialog adding the ".dt" extension, why whould not removing it when changing the file type.